# Ajax Call Interrupted: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, datatables

I have a page in a SpringMVC app which loads a DataTable on startup, which is an Ajax call to fetch data.

If that initial Ajax fetch takes a long time, and I navigate to a different part of the application by clicking somewhere, I get the following:

```
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:284)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.flush(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:514)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:108)
```

JS Call:

```
MyStudy.prototype.configTable = function() {
    var table = $('#myStudies').DataTable();
    table.state.clear();
    table.destroy();

    $('#myStudies').DataTable(
            {
                "pageLength": 10,
                "responsive" : true,
                "processing" : true,
                "serverSide" : false,
                "stateSave" : true,
                "ajax" : {
                    url : '/app/loadStudies',
                    dataSrc :  '',                  
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        handleSystemError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
                    }
                },
                "columns" : [
                        {
                            "data" : "abbreviation"
                        },
                        {
                            "data" : "name"
                        },
```

I want the user to be able to quickly navigate around the app without this error firing, i.e. without waiting for the DataTable to load. If they leave the page, they leave the page, no big deal. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Does the click cause the current page to be unloaded?

Comment: The click navigates to a different JSP. Imagine I have a Tab Menu pointing to different JSPs. The Ajax is from one tab, and then without waiting I click on a different tab which loads a different JSP.